# azure devops variable group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm updating my release definitions to use variable groups. I have more than 100 applications, and different applications have same connection string named differently.

Example - app1 has App1ConnectionString = "Data Source=dv-db1, uid=test, password= password"
app2 has App2ConnectionString = "Data Source=dv-db1, uid=test, password= password"

In my variable groups, I would like to define one variable and use that variable in release definitions of both app1 and app2. Is there a way to accomplish this scenario.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link your variable group:

[image]

Then reference it from your pipeline:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was looking for. I could also add application name to connection string by $(dv-db1)Application Name = App1;